# При нажатии на ссылку открывается скайп

Tags: jquery, html, php, skype

Здравствуйте, существует страничка в интернете на страничке есть значок скайпа (ссылка пустая), как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на эту ссылку у человека открывался скайп? Тоесть если он есть на компьютере у него бы открывался скайп, если нету, то ничего бы не происходило бы. 
Пожалуйста подскажите есть ли такая возможность?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<a href="skype:SkypeUser">SkypeUser</a>
```

http://rotorweb.ru/htmlcss-verstka/ssylki-na-skype-i-icq.html

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="skype:username?chat">Чат с username</a>
<a href="skype:username?call">Позвонить username</a>
<a href="skype:username?add">Добавить username</a>
```